# Softdeletable behaviour and really deleting the entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin, soft-delete

I'm using [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) with [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) to get the soft-deleteable behaviour.

It works really well in the frontend of my application.

In the backend i need the option to "hard" delete entities.

I have disabled the filter in my admin controllers (i use SonataAdmin):

```
$filters = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass())->getFilters();

if (array_key_exists('softdeleteable', $filters->getEnabledFilters())) {
    $filters->disable('softdeleteable');
}
```

This works (soft deleted entities show up in the lists), but when i try to delete it, the entity does get soft-deleted again. How can i force a "hard" delete?

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to disable filter - it just used for filtering records on select. You must disable listener instead:

```
// $em is your EntityManager
foreach ($em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $eventName => $listeners) {
    foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
        if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener) {
            $em->getEventManager()->removeEventListener($eventName, $listener);
        }
    }
}
```

and then call

```
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: How do you re-enable it after this?

Comment: @Jessica, you can use `addEventListener` http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/ContainerAwareEventManager.html#method_addEventListener

Comment: Thanks very much, what I did was store the names of any events I did remove it from, then loop through those and re-add it.

Comment: If your entity manager have more operations, all they will be hard deleted, I personally dont like this alternative. Is useful when you are only performing the delete operation of one entity, but isn't suitable for several operations. (e.g.: $customEntityManager->softDelete($a); $customEntityManager->hardDelete($b); $customEntityManager->flush();) both will be hard deleted.

Comment: this looks very tedious and like a bad DX

Answer (score 7):

No need to create a listener or anything to HARD delete with softdeleteable enabled.

the original softdeleteable event has this line:

```
$reflProp = $meta->getReflectionProperty($config['fieldName']);
$oldValue = $reflProp->getValue($object);
if ($oldValue instanceof \Datetime) {
    continue; // want to hard delete
}
```

All this mean if you:

```
$entity->setDeletedAt(new \Datetime());
$em->flush();
```

And then:

```
$em->remove($entity);
$em->flush();
```

At that point it will be hard deleted.

If you allready have a valid date inside deletedAt field when you call ->flush() after a ->remove($entity) your entity will be hard deleted

Comment: agreed. Which is a bad behavior though, no? at least not transparent at all. "OMG I CALLED REMOVE TWICE ON MY ENTITY OMG OMG" ...

Answer (score 3):

Not the most graceful way : you always can do a real delete with SQL, it will bypass softdeletable

```
$em->createQuery("DELETE MyEntity e WHERE e = :et")->setParameter('et',$entity)->execute();
```

Comment: not graceful? I think just fine, no? just add it to the repo as a function. Way more transparent than double delete -> hard delete

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is a bit old maybe it is useful to someone:

Creating your own event listener might be a better solution:

```
class SoftDeleteableListener extends BaseSoftDeleteableListener
{

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function onFlush(EventArgs $args)
{
    $ea = $this->getEventAdapter($args);
    $om = $ea->getObjectManager();
    //return from event listener if you disabled filter: $em->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
    if (!$om->getFilters()->isEnabled('softdeleteable')) {
        return;
    }

    parent::onFlush($args);
}

}
```

And adding in your config:

```
gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\SoftDeleteableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

source: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1175